# why won't my appendChild work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, twitter-bootstrap

```
function purchase()
{
    var r=document.createElement('div');
    r.className="row";
    alert(r);
    var p=document.createElement('div');
    p.className="purchase-hero-unit";
    alert(p);
    var span1=document.createElement('div');
    span1.className="span3";
    span1.textContent="&nbsp";
    alert(span1);
    var span2=document.createElement('div');
    span2.className="span6";
    alert(span2);
    var span3=document.createElement('div');
    span3.className="span3";
    span3.textContent="&nbsp";
    alert(span3);
    var price=document.getElementById('pPrice').value;
    var name=document.getElementById('pName').value;
    var s=": $";
    var h=document.createElement('h3');
    h.textContent=price+s+name;
    alert(h);
    p.appendChild(h);
    span2.appendChild(p);
    r.appendChild(span1);
    r.appendChild(span2);
    r.appendChild(span3);
    var d=document.getElementById('spendingContainer');
    d.appendChild(r);
    alert(d);
}
```

This is my function to append two text box's input into a twitter bootstrap hero-unit.  spendingContainer is basically just a container, as are any *_*_-hero-unit are basically a hero-unit. If anyone can help fix it, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

JSfiddle outputs:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xa69168c>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0xa6912ec>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xa69168c>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0xa69128c>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

My console says:

```
[18:03:21.744] ReferenceError: reference to undefined property a[o] @ http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js:5
```

and:

```
[18:03:21.744] TypeError: variable b redeclares argument @ http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js:9
```

Comment: you are creating `d` but not adding it to the dom anywhere. Add `d` to an existing element in the dom and it would work

Comment: @karthikr: Can't be. `d` came from `document.getElementById`, and `document.getElementById` will only return elements already in the document.

Comment: @karthikr OP is not creating `d`. He used a `getElementById` for an existing element with the specified `id`. And who up voted that by the way? :)

Comment: Any errors in your console?. Your append child should work unless the code doesn't reach there due to some errors in any of the previous lines...

Comment: I added the appendChild() in place of innerHTML but I still have problems.   JSfiddle outputs a shell form does not validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My biggest problem was actually the onclick part only in the HTML not the js.  Thanks to icktoofay for the help.

Answer (score 2):

These lines are at fault:

```
p.innerHTML=h;
span2.innerHTML=p;
r.innerHTML=span1+span2+span3;
```

`innerHTML` contains HTML strings, not elements. You need to use `appendChild` there, too:

```
p.appendChild(h);
span2.appendChild(p);
r.appendChild(span1);
r.appendChild(span2);
r.appendChild(span3);
```

Comment: Oh never mind, misinterpreted your statement. Reworded: the value assigned to `innerHTML` should be HTML and not DOM elements.